# Sales by month cross tab query using pivot

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to show sales by month using PIVOT in Sql Server 2005.  I know it's a common question, but I just can't figure out what I am missing here:

```
select ShippedYear, 1 as Jan, 2 as Feb
from
(
    select  datepart(year, ss.SHIPPED_DATE) as ShippedYear
          , ss.SHIPPED_AMOUNT as Amount
          , datepart(month, ss.SHIPPED_DATE)) as MonthCode
    from    dbo.SALES_SHIPPER_LINE ssl join dbo.SALES_SHIPPER ss on ss.ID = ssl.SHIPPER_ID
) ps
pivot(
    sum(amt) for MonthCode in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) --this shows error??
) piv;
```

I am getting an error at the "in" clause in my pivot.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your new columns are numbers, you need to escape the names with square brackets:

```
select ShippedYear, 1 as Jan, 2 as Feb
from
(
    select  datepart(year, ss.SHIPPED_DATE) as ShippedYear
          , ss.SHIPPED_AMOUNT as Amount
          , datepart(month, ss.SHIPPED_DATE)) as MonthCode
    from    dbo.SALES_SHIPPER_LINE ssl join dbo.SALES_SHIPPER ss on ss.ID = ssl.SHIPPER_ID
) ps
pivot(
    sum(amt) for MonthCode in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) piv;
```

The square brackets `[]` are used to delimit identifiers. Since the column name begins with a number, this must be delimited. [See MSDN for more details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223962.aspx)